# VIDEOIO ERROR:V4L: Can't open camera by index 0

Tags: command-line, bash, cron, webcam

On a Intel NUC, I have loaded Ubuntu 16.04.  I have disabled the desktop module by making changes to `/etc/default/grub`.  The machine boots in text mode. I have a python program that uses Opencv (`Opencv4.0.0 is currently installed`) and `imutils` library and a webcam.  I have created bash script named `runBot.sh` that runs the python program.  The bash script contains the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
python3 /home/mycomp/rfd/liveCamObject.py
```

When I run it in the terminal window using

```
sh runBot.sh
```

it runs without a problem.  However I am trying to run the program on reboot, hence I have set a cron job which is as follows:

```
@reboot /home/mycomp/runBot.sh
```

Both the sh file and the .py file has sudo `rwx` rights.

When I reboot the machine, on boot I get the following error:

```
error: no video mode activated
```

and after few seconds it boots normally and waits for login and password.  The bash script at reboot gets triggered but throws the error:

```
VIDEOIO ERROR:V4L: can't open camera by index 0.
```

Since the runBot.sh runs from terminal and not with crontab, I tried changing the ownership from `mycomp:mycomp` to `root:mycomp`, it didn't help.  I read that providing

```
sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2
```

and I tried various combinations `v4_l_2, V4_L_2`, etc...I always got an error

```
FATAL: Module `bcm2835-v4l2` not found in directory `/lib/modules/4.15.0-43-generic`
```

How do I enable the video camera on boot?

Answer (score 0):

This might help: (see https://forums.zoneminder.com/viewtopic.php?t=23361)
Do the next:

```
sudo v4l2-ctl --list-devices

sudo chmod 777 /dev/video0
```

for each device

You seem to have repeat the `chmod` after a restart